# Creating an admin only page in php

Tags: php, session

I assume this can simply be done with permissions, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I was trying to make the page check the user for a permission using the code below, otherwise it redirects to home. It always redirects though and I do not know why.

```
    <?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 

if ($_SESSION['permission'] == 0) {
header("Location: ./index.php");
exit;
} else {
if (!isset($_SESSION['authemail'])) {
    header("Location: ./index.php");
    exit;//Redirect to the index
    }
```

Edit: I added a session dump and both the userID and permission are null. What am I missing from here as I cannot figure it out?

```
    <?php
session_start();
include ('../config/config.php');

 /* basic field validation */
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$password = trim ($_POST["password"]);

/* check if details are empty, redirect if they are */
if (empty($email) or empty($password)) {
    $_SESSION["message"] = "You must enter your email and password";
    //Redirect to index
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit;
}
/* sanitise the input */
$email = strip_tags($email);
$password = strip_tags($password);

 /* SQL user selection query, with error handling for the SQL */
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or exit("Error in query: $query. " . mysqli_error());

/* on query success, set sessions for email and userid */
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $_SESSION["authemail"] = $email;
    $_SESSION["userid"] = $id;
    $_SESSION["permission"] = $permission;
    /* redirect the user to the secured page */
    header("Location: ../loggedin.php");
    } else {
    /* display error if login was not successful and redirect to index */
    $_SESSION["message"] = "Could not log in as $email - $query";
    header("index.php");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: put `session_start();` at the top. checking if `$_SESSION` is set or not first, is completely redundant. after that, `var_dump($_SESSION)` to make sure you actually have the values you're expecting.

Comment: we also have no way to tell whether or not those session arrays contain value and if the session was started (elsewhere). Error reporting will help you here. You should start the session regardless. What you have now is failing you. If the session array have values, then you didn't start the session. That is why your code is failing. I'd of posted this comment as an answer TBH, but have chosen not to and posted it as just that, a comment; which in its own right is an answer.

Comment: You're also probably outputtting before header with those leading spaces before the opening php tag.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I have already got a session_start there I just excluded it. I'm sleepy :(

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    }` that only starts the session if there isn't a session open. The `if ($_SESSION['permission'] == 0)` and `if (!isset($_SESSION['authemail']))` will fail since the session needs to be started in there/conditionals.

Comment: strip_tags will not fully sanitize your input. You should use a binded query instead of a regular query.

Comment: You are not using the $row array properly. $_SESSION['authemail'] = $row['email'];

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a flag in the database for someone who is an admin. Then on any specific page that only admins can access you should check this user variable.

```
if(!$user->isAdmin()){
    header("Location: ./login.php");
    exit;
}
```

If you do not have a $user object available, simply call a function that can query the database for the necessary variable.

```
 if(!isUserAdmin()){
    header("Location: ./login.php");
     exit;
 }
```

Also since both cases of yours redirect to index.php, you can combine the statements:

```
if($_SESSION['permission'] == 0 || !isset($_SESSION['authemail'])){
     header("Location: ./index.php");
     exit;
}
```

Make sure you are debugging to make sure the SESSION values are set/get as expected. Your code is redirecting because one of the conditions is true. Debug and find the bug.